# Tags in "Fill out your CV" are borked

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The fields for adding tags in the "Fill out your CV" dialog on the new integrated jobs site seem borked.

- The tags are displayed too far down.
- If a tag in the middle is deleted, all tags to the right disappear.... until you press the right arrow key. I assume an extra newline is added, which will push them under the box.

Mandatory beautiful screenshot with red hand-drawn <s>circles</s>ovals. Screenshot has been made on Chrome 47.0.2526.80 on Windows 10.

[image: Tags are displayed weirdly]

Comment: Could be your version of Chrome? The latest is 47.0.2526.106. I tested on both Windows 10 and OSX and couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Juice It updated now, but it still happens, even after disabling all extensions. Did you test it by pressing [this button](http://imgur.com/sSzrFQz)? The tags on the "edit cv" tab work fine, it's just the dialog that opens when clicking the button in the side-menu on the "search jobs" tab.

Comment: Made a screencast of it for clarity: https://youtu.be/Wkgb1hX1fBE

Comment: Perfect. I was on a different page. I'll let them know.

Comment: @MartinSmith Good catch.