# "Fill out your CV" too many tags and strange edit behavior?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stack-overflow-jobs

I assume my CV profile was transferred from the old Jobs site.  I have more tags than will fit in the rather small single-line input box, and the tags overflow off the right side with no apparent way to see or edit them.

[image]

Clicking in the tag input field produces strange behavior:

1. If you click on a tag all the ones to the right disappear.  If you hit ESCAPE at that point no damage is done, but I'd rather not accidentally delete some tags so I haven't gone past that point.
2. If you click on whitespace in the input field (above a tag or to the far left), then ALL the tags disappear.

Comment: What I have done in this case when I did use SO Careers, is I clicked on one tag (which causes it to go into edit mode) and then I used either the right arrow key to "scroll" to the end of the text field, or I pressed the End key to go to the end of the text field. You can also hold down Ctrl+Left or Ctrl+Right arrow keys to "scroll" faster. I haven't had any accidental mistakes when doing this, but it does feel like everything's going to explode, so something needs to be done.

Comment: I think that teh textfield should either be made larger by default, or it should "wrap" around its content (shrink and/or expand to fit its content) or it should show scrollbars or allow us to resize it.

Comment: "Edit Mode" seems to be broken as well.

Comment: If you're comfortable with HTML, you could right-click one of those tags and select "inspect element" and then just edit the values of the tags in the browser's dev tools window - it should actually be quicker than stuffing around with the tags themselves. Then just submit the form as normal. But I know... it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312519/tags-in-fill-out-your-cv-are-borked

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the bug report!

The mysterious disappearing-tags issue should be fixed now. They weren't disappearing, they were just being pushed off the side of the screen by a big blank box ;)

You can scroll to view tags that are off the right-hand side of the input using the arrow keys.

Comment: The overflow issue is still occurring for me. The arrow keys do work, but it makes editing tags rather difficult.