# Removing a tag on CV removes multiple tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On this form I was trying to edit the tags under **"Tech you want to work with"**.

[image: popup]

Now the strange thing that I've found is that when I tried to remove the tag [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) it also removed [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). I then tried to remove [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and two other tags, [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), also get removed. The same happened with both tag input fields.

Comment: You can't know python if you don't know ruby, you can't know jquery and java since you don't know javascript which both are based of... sounds logical!

Comment: @Braiam You certainly can know Java without knowing JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Honestly guys? So you can't know programming if you don't know assembly? And you can't know assembly if you don't know embedded systems, and subsequently binary logic and probability and algebra and calculus? What kind of a logic is that?!

Comment: @Xenatisch I think Braiam's comment was meant to be sarcasm/a joke... Especially since Python predates Ruby by 5 years or so

Comment: Are you sure it is not [this issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312519/tags-in-fill-out-your-cv-are-borked)? (aka they are there, but they are on a newline, thus invisible)

Comment: @Sumurai8 I didn't checked it yet but if it's the same then they should have counted it on but yet they didn't solved that bug interesting I think SO is not counting as a bug

Comment: FYI the sheer fact that you blanked out the company name made me go to your careers page to check what you were hiding.

Comment: Lol:-) @AshleyMedway